# Calling a QMainWindow method in its instance class method

Tags: c++, qt, methods, qt4, qmainwindow

I have a `MainWindow` class

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    customClass * obj;
public:
    void foo(bool);
}
```

Here is my customClass:

```
class customClass 
{
    void foo1(bool);
}
```

Now, I want to call `foo()` method in `foo1()`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the constructor of your `customClass` take a pointer to a `MainWindow` which it stores in a member variable for later use.

```
class customClass 
{
public:
  customClass(MainWindow* mainWindow)
  : mainWindow_(mainWindow)
  {
  }

  void foo1(bool b) {
    mainWindow_->foo(b);
  }

private:
  MainWindow* mainWindow_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of way - using of dependency injection pattern: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

```
struct A;
struct B
{
  B( A& a );

void foo1()
{
  m_a.foo();
}

private:
  A& m_a;
}

struct A
{
  void foo(){}
  B m_b;
}
```

Comment: can't it be simple, for a beginner?

Comment: It's simple as much, as it can be. You should pass a pointer or a reference of class MainWindow to a constructor of class customClass and save in in some member. Then you may use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your MainWindow implements singleton pattern (if it's applicable to your design), then you can directly get an instance from any place you like.